# I have several running pods, how do I add a replication controller to those existing pods?

Tags: openshift-origin

Here is the scenario.  I have a bunch of pods, services and routes already created.   However there is no replication controller.  How do I just add a replication controller to those existing objects.

Here's the sample yaml for the kubernetes objects.  https://github.com/openshift/origin/tree/release-3.9/examples/wordpress

Answer (score 0):

oc run mysql --image=openshift/mysql-55-centos7 --env="MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=yourpassword" --env="MYSQL_USER=wp_user" --env="MYSQL_PASSWORD=wp_pass" --env="MYSQL_DATABASE=wp_db" --port=3306 --expose

oc run wordpress --image=wordpress --env="WORDPRESS_DB_USER=wp_user" --env="WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD=wp_pass" --env="WORDPRESS_DB_NAME=wp_db" --env="WORDPRESS_DB_HOST=mysql" --port=80 --expose

modify them after dc creation to add storage to those pods (used the UI) and then create your own route (used the UI).